# Bootstrap: Which units should I use to make a form, looking the same on different screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie in CSS, so maybe my question is incorrect. But I want to put a login form with correct sizes over the rest of my site.

When you use Bootstrap's `.col-*-*` classes it makes the sizes correct on mobile screens with high density and on desktop screens with low density. But I guess I can't use `.col-*-*` in my case. Also I can't use `px` units because then my form will be too small on mobile screens, and I can't use `cm` units because then my form will be to big on mobile screens. How should I set the size of my form then?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel you can't use `col-*-*`?

Answer (score 0):

You simply put the form in a "col" (As suggest by @Ross Wilson) and the form becomes responsive (basically speaking)

Take the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">

    <form>
      <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Text</label>
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="selectbasic">Select</label>
          <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
           <option value="1">Option</option>
           <option value="2">Option</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```